# SpringBootでthymeleafを使ってのエラー

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

"SpringBoot2プログラミング"という教本で学習中ですが、その中の140ページ目で躓いております。

thymeleafを使ってindex.htmlをブラウザで表示させたいのですがうまくいきません。

環境は以下の通りです。

- springboot 2.0.3.RELEASE
- windows 10
- sts-3.9.4.RELEASE
- jdk1.8.0_171
- maven
- thymeleaf

STSのRun As → Spring boot Appを行うとポップアップでError in Workspace　となり、内容なErrors exist in required project(s): Project_Name Proceed with launch?　と出ます。この画面でキャンセルとせずにproceedをクリックしたあとブラウザでhttp://localhost:8080を確認するWhitelabel Error Page　となってます。

以下各ソースです。
HeloController.java

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class HeloController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}   
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>top page</title>
<style type="text/css">
h1{font-size:18pt; font-weight:bold; color:gray;}
body{font-sie:13pt; color:gray; margin:5px 25px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hele page</h1>
<p class="msg">this is Thymeleaf sample page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tenpat</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tenpat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Tenpat</name>
    <description>project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

わかる方、ご教授願います。
また、私自身ここには初めて質問するので、何か至らない点があるかもしれませんがその際はご指摘いただけると幸いです。

Comment: プロジェクトにビルドできないようなエラーがあるのではないですかね。STSの画面下部に「Problems」というタブがあると思います。そこにエラーが表示されていませんか？

Comment: エラーありました。Errors (59 items) で先頭はFailed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE
と書かれてます。

Comment: 59件エラーがあるみたいですね。プロキシーサーバーなどに邪魔されて、依存ライブラリ取得できないのかも。`mvn clean install`でビルドは成功しますか？

Comment: 現在STSを使っているのですが、その中のRunメニューのRun AsのMaven  Cleanを行い、Successとでました。次にMaven Installを行い、これもSuccessと出ました。その後教本通りSpring Boot Appを起動しましたが状況は変わりませんでした。現在自宅内で作業中でして、プロキシは特につけてはないと思います。

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse`とか実行しても駄目ですかね？

Comment: 解決しました。どうやらタイピングミスのようです。この教本のホームページにソースがありましたので、試しに張り付けたところ動きました。お騒がせしました。

Comment: でもそのあとで自分が書いたソースに試しにもどしたのですが動きました…、こうなると原因不明ですが追及はしないことにします。